# Is something like p.a.theming diazo.debug possible with diazo standalone?

Tags: plone, diazo

With p.a.theming it is possible to use diazo.debug to get an overlay containing your annotated rules. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#theme-debugging

[image: Example of the info shown when using diazo.debug=1]

The overlay shows what rules are matched when performing a transform of a specific page of your content - see the image above.

Is something similar possible when running diazo standalone with paster?
That is, is it possible to show info about matched rules when doing a transform?

The diazo command line tools (diazocompiler, diazopreprocessor, diazorun) only show info about compiling your rules to xslt as far as I know - or is more possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you `pip install diazo` (I'd use a virtualenv), you'll get three command-line scripts:

- diazocompiler
- diazopreprocessor
- diazorun

that will allow you to run all the diazo operations from the command line. You''ll be most interested in `diazorun` with the runtrace command-line option which will allow you to annotate a rules file with the results of a transformation. It will tell you all you want to know -- and more.

Comment: the diazo.debug feature of p.a.theming shows matched rules when rendering a specific page - that is, when performing a transform. The diazo command line tools only shows you info when compiling your rules to xslt (as far as I know). I expanded my question a bit.